# Convert Variant in For Each to range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, variables

Is there any way to cast a Variant variable to Range variable in VBA?

Let me explain why I need to do this.
I fill a Dictionary with Ranges as Keys, and new values as items:

```
        dChanges.add .cells(rowNewTask, rngTaskId.column), TaskId
        dChanges.add .cells(rowNewTask, rngNumSection.column), numSection
        dChanges.add .cells(rowNewTask, rngSection.column), Section
        dChanges.add .cells(rowNewTask, rngMajorTask.column), majorTask
        dChanges.add .cells(rowNewTask, rngSubTask.column), subTask
        dChanges.add .cells(rowNewTask, rngUnitType.column), unitType
```

Then for each item I apply changes using some functions:

```
        For Each RngI In dChanges
            RngI.value = dChanges(RngI)
            highlightCell RngI
        Next
```

RngI needs to be of type Variant so I can use it in a For loop, but  `highlightCell RngI` requires that RngI is Range.

Comment: Why does `highlightCell` need to take the range object `ByRef` anyway?

Comment: @BigBen It looks you are right. I did not see your answer... I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim RngI As Range` works for a dictionary containing ranges.

Sample code:

```
Sub foobar()
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    d.Add Sheet1.Range("A1"), "foo"
    d.Add Sheet1.Range("A2"), "bar"
    
    Dim RngI As Range
    For Each RngI In d
        RngI.Value = d(RngI)
    Next
End Sub
```

This writes "foo" and "bar" into cells A1 and A2.